# Get Thread exit code after running ShellExecuteEx

Tags: c++, c, windows

How can the exit code of the main thread be retrieved, after having run ShellExecuteEx() in asychronous mode?

The process exit code can simply be retrieved as follows:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO execInfo;
execInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
execInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;

ShellExecuteEx(&execInfo);

/* Get process exit code. */
DWORD processExitCode;
GetExitCodeProcess(execInfo.hProcess, &processExitCode);
```

But how can the exit code of the main thread be retrieved? What should be passed to GetExitCodeThread()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the exit code of the primary process thread - one has to obtain its `HANDLE`. Unfortunately `ShellExecuteEx` doesn't return you this (it returns only the `HANDLE` of the newly created process).

One could also enumerate all the threads in a particular process and open their handles (`OpenThread`). Thus, you could create a process in a "suspended" state, get the handle of its only thread (which didn't start execution yet), and then go on.

Alas, `ShellExecuteEx` neither allows you to create a new process in a suspended state.

So that I don't see a clean way to achieve what you want. I'd suggest the following:

1. Why would you want the exit code of the primary thread anyway? Perhaps the exit code of the process will be enough?
2. Consider using `CreateProcess`. It has the needed functionality.
3. Some dirty tricks may help, like injecting DLLs into the newly created process (hooking) and etc.

Answer (score 1):

The exit code of the main thread is equal to the exit code of the process IMHO.

Comment: It doesn't have to. One may call `ExitProcess(...)` with any code